# long value with 0 on left

Tags: java, long-integer, octal

Why this behavior happens?

```
long value = 123450;
System.out.println("value: " + value);
```

value: 123450

```
long value = 0123450;
//           ^
System.out.println("value: " + value);
```

value: 42792

What is this 42792?

Answer (score 7):

> **Why this behavior happens?**

Just as literals starting with `0x` are treated as hexadecimal numbers (base 16), literals starting with a `0` are treated as [**octal numbers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), i.e., numbers in base 8.

(Try writing 0789, and you'll see that the compiler will complain.)

> **What is this 42792?**

The number 123450 in base 8 represents the number

**1**×8<sup>5</sup> + **2**×8<sup>4</sup> + **3**×8<sup>3</sup> + **4**×8<sup>2</sup> + **5**×8<sup>1</sup> + **0**×8<sup>0</sup> = 42792

Answer (score 5):

If you prefix a number with a zero, it is understood to be octal (base 8). However, println writes it in base 10.

123450 octal = 42792 decimal.

Answer (score 5):

That's the way java represent an octal literal. Take a look at this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

If what you want is to print something with zeros in the left you need to use **DecimalFormat** format method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

In that case you do this:

```
long value = 123450;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
System.out.println("value: " + df.format(value));
```

Answer (score 3):

Octal literal. See Java Language Specification, 3.10.1 for detailed, albeit somewhat dry, description of Java number literals. To find and study more fun stuff like that, refer to 'Java puzzlers' [book](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This feature dates back to the early 'C' days. A leading '0' is for octal, a leading '0x' is for hexidecimal. It has been proposed that '0b' be for binary numbers for JDK 7.

You can parse such a number with `Integer.decode(String)` which also accepts a leading '#' as a hexi-decimal number.