# Why is Long value not printed correctly in java?

Tags: java

i have declared `Long checkRandom=0101010101l;`
but when I am printing checkRandom it printed `checkRandom==17043521`
what was the reason its taking `checkRandom=17043521` not `checkRandom=0101010101`

Comment: Numbers that start with a zero are treated as octal.

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540179/long-value-with-0-on-left).

Comment: Seems more a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611185/unexpected-int-integer-behavior-when-number-starts-by-0) to me.

Comment: @BackSlash there is a myriad of potential duplicate questions.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage yes you are right.thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the leading 0:

```
Long checkRandom=101010101l
```